# Python Selenium scrape the price which is contained in a custom attribute

Tags: python, selenium

After hours of trying I manage to scrape data from a marketplace with selenium.
With this code here I took the titles

```
website = 'https://www.skroutz.gr/c/40/kinhta-thlefwna.html?from=families'
title_list=[]
price_list=[]
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(website)
#titles = driver.find_elements("class name",'js-sku-link')
titles = driver.find_elements("class name",'js-sku-link')
for title in titles:
    print(title.get_attribute('title'))
```

I took the titles with the class name but I am curious how can I take the price which the structure is like the following screenshot.

[image]

What I should use in this case ?

Comment: You can use `driver. findElement(By.xpath())`

Comment: But how will be the xpath in order to extract all the prices in this case ?

Comment: Do you need prices from all the cards in the page?

Comment: Yes exactly. I need the prices from all the cards.

Comment: okay, wait a jiffy I am providing an answer

Comment: Is working properly thank you very much. I am trying know to have all the info in table and to check if the data are accurate.

Comment: Also can you help on how i can scrape the title without the `.get_attribute('title')` in order to add all the elements in a single for loop.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `'find_elements_by_xpath'` to print the `prices`.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
priceLink = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value = '//a[@data-e2e-testid="sku-price-link"]')

for price in priceLink:
    print(price.text)
```